# How to turn "find -exec" results into different columns?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, find

When launching a `find -exec` I get a list of results, separated by colons. Is there a way to turn those colons into some kind of "columns" separators (preferably a list of spaces)?

Turn:

```
Prompt> find ./ -name "*.*" -exec grep "namespace" {} /dev/null \;

./Alarm/AddedHandler.cs:namespace Alarm
./Alarm/DeletedHandler.cs:namespace Alarm
./Alarm/UpdatedHandler.cs:namespace Alarm
./Connections/AddedHandler.cs:namespace Connections
./Connections/DeletedHandler.cs:namespace Connections
./Connections/UpdatedHandler.cs:namespace Connections
./Robot.Api/AddedHandler.cs:namespace Robot
./Robot.Api/DeletedHandler.cs:namespace Robot
./Robot.Api/UpdatedHandler.cs:namespace Robot
```

... into:

```
Prompt> find ./ -name "*.*" -exec grep "namespace" {} /dev/null \; | <turn_colon_into_list_of_spaces>

./Alarm/AddedHandler.cs         : namespace Alarm
./Alarm/DeletedHandler.cs       : namespace Alarm
./Alarm/UpdatedHandler.cs       : namespace Alarm
./Connections/AddedHandler.cs   : namespace Connections
./Connections/DeletedHandler.cs : namespace Connections
./Connections/UpdatedHandler.cs : namespace Connections
./Robot.Api/AddedHandler.cs     : namespace Robot
./Robot.Api/DeletedHandler.cs   : namespace Robot
./Robot.Api/UpdatedHandler.cs   : namespace Robot
```

(I don't care whether or not the colons are still present.)

Comment: `find ... | column -ts':' -o' : '`

Comment: Why do you have `/dev/null` as part of exec?

Comment: The job of `find` isn't to format its output; it simply writes the file names it finds separated by linefeeds. (The output of `grep` is *entirely*  out of its control; `-exec` simply runs an external command and uses its exit status in determining whether a file is "found" or not; the output of that command is just a side effect.)

Comment: How come output of `grep` doesn't contain another `:` after search string `namespace`?

Comment: @knittl: I replaced the word "semicolon" by "colon" in my question (English is only my fourth language, so it's not perfect :-) ). I add `/dev/null` to the `find -exec` command in order to force showing the filename (it's a `grep` quirk: `grep something filename` does not show the filename, while `grep something multiple filenames` does, and adding `/dev/null` makes `grep` believe I'm looking in multiple filenames :-) ).

Comment: @Dominique you can always run `grep -l` to show file names :)

Comment: @knittl: `grep -l` **only** shows filenames, while I want filenames and search results, in two separate columns for easy readability.

Comment: @Dominique oh sorry, you are right! If using GNU grep, there's `-H`. As a GNU extension not really portable. Thanks for sharing this little trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe the output to [`column`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/column.1.html):

```
find ... | column -ts:
```

Answer (score 2):

This `find + sed` should work for you:

```bash
find . -type f -exec grep -H "namespace" {} + | sed 's/:/\t\t\t/'
```

Here:

- Using `-H` option in `grep` to get filenames in output
- Using `+` for more efficient `find` execution
- Using `sed` to replace **only first `:`** with 3 tabs